# Creating Folder at Network in Java

Tags: java, stream, filestream

I want to send folder at network,  according to my code if a folder contains files it send them successfully, but it does not create a folder on client side if folder contains inside folder?

Server Code:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
File file = new File("home/");
File[] children = file.listFiles();

if (children != null) {
  for (File child : children) {
    all.add(child);  

    if(!child.isDirectory()){
      oos.writeObject(child.getName());
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(child);  

      while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {  
        oos.writeObject(bytesRead);  
        oos.writeObject(Arrays.copyOf(buffer, buffer.length));  
      }   

    }
  }
}
```

Client Code:

```
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(theSocket.getOutputStream());
ois = new ObjectInputStream(theSocket.getInputStream());

out = new PrintWriter(theSocket.getOutputStream( ));

while (true) {
  Object o = ois.readObject();

  File file = new File(o.toString());

  if(file.isDirectory())
    File Dir = new File("new/").mkdir();
  if(!file.isDirectory()){
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(o.toString());    

    do {  
      o = ois.readObject();
      bytesRead = (Integer) o;
      o = ois.readObject();  
      buffer = (byte[])o;  

      fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);  
    }
    while (bytesRead == BUFFER_SIZE);  
    fos.close(); 
  }
}
```

It does not show any error, instead it creates an anonymous file of name (folder on server side) on client side. Please tell me what's wrong with my code!

Comment: You sure you need this slash there? `new File("new/").mkdir()`

Comment: yes, no issue with it, just used it for creating folder in the same directory

Comment: I'm sorry, just wanted to clarify what you are trying to explain: "I want to send folder at network" = You want to send a File object's instance (a Directory) through the network to a given destination. "according to my code if a folder contains files it send them successfully".. are you using an endless loop? Why not creating a scheduled task to verify this folder from time to time? (http://quartz-scheduler.org/). "but it does not create a folder on client side if folder contains inside folder?".. what? Sorry, I can't understand this question.

Comment: It is either serialization or java.io. behavior. It seems nothing to do with the Network. The question is not clear at all. But, lots of unrelated code. -1

Comment: @theMarceloR, files inside the folder sent successfully, bcz of file stream, but when folder contian inside folder, how can i send indication to client that it is a inside folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (part of) your answer is recursion. There are a few ways to do it. One is to send bytesRead as -1 or NULL for directories and recurse on the client side as well, another, which I'll show below (somewhat inefficiently), is to send the relative path with the file and create directories as required on the client side.

**Server side:**

```
void processFile(File file, String path)
{
  if (file.isDirectory())
  {
    File[] children = file.listFiles();
    for (File child : children)
    {
      all.add(child);
      processFile(child, path + file.getName() + "/");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    oos.writeObject(path + child.getName());
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(child);  
    while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {  
      oos.writeObject(bytesRead);  
      oos.writeObject(buffer);  
    }
    oos.writeObject(BUFFER_SIZE);
  }
}
```

Called with `processFile(file, "")` or `processFile(file, "/")`.

Say something like `oos.writeObject("")` after the call and do a check on the client side similar to `name.length() == 0` to know when to stop.

**Client side:**

```
while (true)
{
  String name = (String)ois.readObject();
  if (name.length() == 0) break;
  // "/new/" is the absolute path of the directory where you want all these files to be created
  name += "/new/";

  File dir = new File(name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf('/')));
  if (!dir.exists())
    dir.mkdirs();

  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(name));    

  bytesRead = (Integer) ois.readObject();
  while (bytesRead != BUFFER_SIZE)
  {  
    buffer = (byte[])ois.readObject();
    fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);  
    bytesRead = (Integer) ois.readObject();
  }
  fos.close(); 
}
```